# How can I extract fields from output of more +n?

Tags: windows, shell

I need to get certain fields from the output of the more +n command in Windows. The output of the more command is shown below. I need to extract certain field from this output.

```
     Backup                       SAP L01_xyzabc_d01p001_PBW_ON_Daily Completed                 full    9/17/2013 6:00:05 PM     0:00     5:49          2360.00          1        0          0     254    100% 2013/09/17-135  
     Backup                       SAP L01_xyzabc_d01p001_PEC_ON_Daily Completed                 full    9/17/2013 7:00:05 PM     0:00     1:37           549.89          1        0          0      75    100% 2013/09/17-142  
     Backup                       SAP L01_xyzabc_d01p001_PPI_ON_Daily Completed                 full    9/17/2013 7:00:07 PM     0:00     2:04           656.00          1        0          0     104    100% 2013/09/17-143  
     Backup                       SAP L01_xyzabc_d01p001_PEP_ON_Daily Completed                 full    9/17/2013 8:00:05 PM     0:00     0:09            12.89          1        0          0      15    100% 2013/09/17-148  
     Backup                       SAP L01_xyzabc_d01p001_PDI_ON_Daily Completed                 full    9/17/2013 9:00:05 PM     0:00     0:07             5.63          1        0          0      14    100% 2013/09/17-156  
     Backup                       SAP L01_xyzabc_d01p001_PSM_ON_Daily Completed                 full    9/17/2013 10:00:06 P     0:00     0:22            92.08          1        0          0      21    100% 2013/09/17-161  
     Backup                       SAP L01_xyzabc_d01p001_PMD_ON_Daily Completed                 full    9/17/2013 11:00:06 P     0:00     0:09             9.53          1        0          0      26    100% 2013/09/17-169
```

Can this be done without installing anything or without using PowerShell?

-Louie

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a for loop. This is a batch file version.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2,3" %%a in ('more +n ...') do (
    echo %%a %%b %%c
)
```

It would depend on the columns you wanted. You can see more info by typing `help for` on the command-line.